# Sharepoint WebPart with AjaxToolkit's Accordion control

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, web-parts

Do you guys have any resources on creating a Sharepoint webpart that uses the AjaxToolkit controls?  I need to create a webpart that uses the Accordion control and I can't find any complete tutorial or walkthrough.  I prefer a tutorial/article that doesn't use SmartPart.

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointajax

Answer (score 1):

The ajax toolkit and sharepoint don't play very nicely together. The main reason for this is the lack of DOCTYPE declaration in SharePoint's default MasterPage (why they did this, I'll never know).

Your best bet, in my humble opinion, is to abandon the ajax control toolkit and use JQuery. If you follow the link to JQuery UI, you will find that they have implemented an accordian control that works very nicely across a wide range of browsers/environments.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com) Rad Controls for ASP.Net Ajax can be deployed in the Sharepoint environment and have a menu control with the Accordion behavior out of the box.  It may save you some time.